# Restricted Rotation using electromagnets

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electromagnetism, magnets

I was wondering if I could restrict the rotation of a part over another in one direction alone using an electromagnet but allowing me to have a continuous rotation if forced (maybe by using some leverage?) to rotate in that direction.

The concern with using a ratcheted device is intermittent restriction- what I am looking for is a continuous restriction - at any angle of rotation.

I would like to add an image to the question, but not sure how. thus attaching a google drive image. url is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ugcji9pDeVQiaCE9BgmFnaj6gt8gPMcf/view

Here, 1 will rotate clockwise or counter cw based on an input (not shown) and 2 rotates w.r.t 1, but need an electromagnet that can stop its rotation in counter clockwise direction unless otherwise turned using a 20 kg force (that is leveraged from elsewhere)

Comment: Please explain more as to why a ratchet will not work. The tooth spacing on a ratchet can be very small so that there is almost no reverse movement possible. Also, a magnet would have to be rather large to apply the given force.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I agree to the teeth spacing, but still theoretically it's not a continuous motion